# Clickonce with Dropbox

Tags: clickonce, dropbox, azure-storage

I was looking for ClickOnce publishing with Dropbox and found *[I need people's opinion on how to update a ClickOnce application through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095482/i-need-peoples-opinion-on-how-to-update-a-clickonce-app-through-ftp)*.

It seems that the answer is working for the user, but when I tried to implement it using my Dropbox account, it didn't work and I was getting a different URL pattern.

One sample:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4bco6ezixre165k/QCjfk7jy6R/PublishedApps

So it seems that my Dropbox account is using HTTPS with a different URL pattern.

I double checked Dropbox settings and found nothing regarding HTTPS configuration.

What could be the problem?

Comment: After digging more in Dropbox URLs, it seems that the problem is because Dropbox now gives 2 different base URLs for files in the same folder which makes it impossible to use it with Clickonce.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Dropbox can't be used anymore for ClickOnce deployments (at least for now), I ended up using Azure storage.

I have found the following articles useful for setting things:

- *[How to host a ClickOnce deployment in Azure Blob Storage](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/)*
- *[Host your ClickOnce deployment in Azure for pennies per month](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/host-your-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-for-pennies-per-month/)*

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the issue, I'm still using Dropbox to publish a ClickOnce application, but I am doing so through a public link. Dropbox discontinued public folders for new users in October 2012 but existing users, such as myself, retained the functionality.

I have found this method highly effective since Dropbox only uploads the changed files, not the entire folder every time. This means that I can do an update and the new version is available within seconds.

@Adel: Azure seems to be a viable alternative. I just found that the publishing takes far longer than to Dropbox, perhaps because there is no Azure servers in South Africa.

Comment: On further investigation I found that new users can also enable the public folder (https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en), ClickOnce functionality works perfectly.

Comment: It looks like this is no longer the case, `Currently only Pro and Dropbox for Business users can enable Public folders, so you may have to upgrade first.`